The Public Network Terms of Service navigation should include all subsections
In order to increase transparency and better comply with the various (inter-)national privacy/transparency laws, I recommend expanding the navigation section of the Public Network Terms of Service. Currently, it only lists the 11 top-level section:

It should include all subsection:

This change would make it easier to get an overview of the TOS and to navigate it, especially as things like "Mandatory Arbitration" are not necessary standard to a TOS (at least internationally) and may not be expected by users.
